# R: performing same task on multiple matrices

Tags: r

I have about 150 matrices, each with a name in the convention of "BID_xxx" (for example: BID_ABL, BID_BGA). I would like to split the first column of each of these matrices into two using substr. So, for example: `BID_ABL[,5] = substr(BID_ABL[,1],1,10)`

Would anyone be able to help me find a way of doing this without writing out the above line 150 times, once for each matrix?

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `get` and `assign` are your friends here:

```
for (n in ls()[grep("^BID_",ls())]) {
  x <- get(n)
  x[,5] <- substr(x[,1],1,10)
  assign(n, x)
}
```

Should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
allnames<- ls(pat='BID_')

for(j in 1:length(allnames))  print(get(allnames[j])[1])
```

Where you'd replace "print" with your substring function.
Edit: Sam's answer is essentially the same.  How you get the list of object names depends on what other stuff is in your environment.

Comment: never noticed you can put a pattern into `ls`, very useful!

Comment: @Carl, thanks for the code, this ls function is great. In the end I used Sam's code as I was struggling to use the assign function with this code. Thanks again!